# Could a change in our website's address potentially be affecting the queries people use to find it?

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress

We moved our Wordpress website from a .co address to a .com a few months ago, and ever since we did that, the queries that were the most interesting for our business stopped making our site appear on Google. No impressions were generated from those queries at all from that moment onward. So that's what we are interested in solving.

The change of address on Google Search Console was initiated in December of last year, but the .co property still shows that the site is moving to another address, and some of the pages (exactly 6 of them) are still shown as indexed.

What we did was make every .co URL redirect to the .com one, and I am certain this is working. Also, the searches on the old property are clearly declining, so the migration appears to be actually working. However, the fact that it hasn't been finished yet makes us think that we've probably made a mistake somewhere in the process.

What could be making our site not show up with some specific queries, as it used to with the previous URL?

**EDIT:**

To clarify, the searches (queries) we want to appear for are the searches for our company's industry and for the services we offer. This used to happen when we had the previous address.

**EDIT 2:**

The redirects from the previous address don't work if you try to use HTTPS. But without it, they work as expected.

Comment: Have you typed those 6 urls in the browser to see what happens ?

Comment: Did the content change? Were the redirects to the exact same page on the new domain? Did the robots.txt or meta robots tag change?

Comment: Yes, I did visit those 6 URLs. They all refuse to connect.

Comment: The content remained pretty much the same. We added new pages, and also new blog entries, but the content in the previously existing pages is still there. We've only recently modified one of the old pages, but since this problem is older, it may be unrelated. Besides, the content still remained pretty much the same.
The redirects are to the exact same page on the new domain, yes. And yes, I changed the robots.txt recently, but it's also probably unrelated since the problem is from before the change, too, and our main pages (the ones that have the most relevant content) are indexed.

Comment: Does that not mean that redirection is not working?

Comment: "They all refuse to connect." that should tell you something :P

Comment: Fair point. Though those redirections don't work because they have "https://" at the beginning. If I take that out on the browser and type only the address, they work as expected. It's interesting because that's how all of the redirects work on the page. None work if I use "https://" at the beginning. Still, there are only six of them indexed. The other ones have already been taken from the index.

Should I be more concerned over this? I can't clearly see the relation to the question's problem, nor do I know what it should be telling me. The new address works when I write "https://" with it.

Comment: To add more clarification, it's not the URLs from the current address that are giving this "refused to connect" problem, but the ones that remain from the previous address (only while using https). That's why I can't see how it could be affecting the current site, though I understand something must surely be going on since they're still listed in the index. Also, the URLs are from blog posts and case studies. Not the main page or any other more relevant part of the site.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure **every url** redirects properly to the new server using a **301 redirection** code.

All these redirects must work correctly:

- http://old.example.com redirect to https://new.example.com
- https://old.example.com redirect to https://new.example.com
- http://new.example.com redirect to https://new.example.com

As you can see, every redirection should lead to https://new.example.com

You are losing visitors/traffic, because your old URLs in HTTPS mode are not responding properly, without a redirect or content.

There are several tools you can use to ensure that you are using a **301 redirection** code. Try googling for **HTTP response header check tool** and testing your urls there.